# .jar file will not open with player added

Tags: java, jar, mp3

I have created a game in java using netbeans that uses a player to play background music. The program compiles well and works fine, but when I create a .jar file to test it, the .jar file doesn't even open. I'm lost. The .jar file will open without the player code in it. Any help?

```
Player audioPlayer = null;
    try {
        audioPlayer = Manager.createPlayer(new MediaLocator(getClass().getResource("/sounds/poop.mp3")));
    } catch (IOException ex) {
        Logger.getLogger(playerPanel.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
    } catch (NoPlayerException ex) {
        Logger.getLogger(playerPanel.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
    }
    audioPlayer.start();
```

Any ideas or alternatives to achieve the same result would be helpful. If any extra code or information if needed, just request it.

Comment: What do you mean by "jar doesn't even open". How are you running the jar ?

Comment: It is an executable file. It does not open in the command line or by double clicking it.

Answer (score 0):

Do this in all of your catchs:

> ex.printStackTrace();
>               FileWriter out = new FileWriter("stack");
>               BufferedWriter writer = new BufferedWriter(out);
>               writer.write(ex.getMessage());
>               writer.close();

Open the file with notepad and see what error it gives you.  My guess is that it gives you NoPlayerException, so that you audioPlayer is null.  I bet if you do Player audioPlayer = Manager... inside try instead of initializing it outside of it your program will stop crashing.  There might not be sound, but it won't crash.

I'm trying to solve a similiar kind of problem :(